# mixup TCP sessions in pcap file to new pcap file

Tags: bash, tshark, pcap

I need to shuffle TCP sessions from `pcap` file to new file. How can I do it? The following scripts don't work for me.

---

To mix up sessions in a `pcap` file using Tshark or Wireshark, you can use the following steps:

1. Rename the original `pcap` file to something else (optional): This step is not necessary but can help keep track of the original pcap file. You can use the following command to rename the file:

   ```shell
   mv original.pcap original_original.pcap
   ```
2. Extract individual sessions from the original pcap file using Tshark: Use Tshark to extract individual sessions from the original pcap file into separate pcap files, like this:

   ```shell
   tshark -r original_original.pcap -Y "tcp.stream == X" -w session_X.pcap
   ```

   Replace `X` with the desired session number. Repeat this command for each session you want to extract, incrementing `X` accordingly.
3. Mix up the extracted pcap files: Use a bash script to randomly concatenate the extracted pcap files into a new mixed-up pcap file. Here is an example script (`mixup_pcap.sh`) that uses the `shuf` command to shuffle the filenames randomly and then appends them to a new file:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   output_pcap="mixed_sessions.pcap"
   session_files=(session_*.pcap)

   # Randomly shuffle the session files
   shuffled_files=($(shuf -e "${session_files[@]}"))

   # Concatenate the shuffled pcap files into a new mixed-up pcap file
   for file in "${shuffled_files[@]}"; do
       cat "$file" >> "$output_pcap"
   done

   echo "Mixed-up pcap file created: $output_pcap"
   ```

   Save the above script to `mixup_pcap.sh`, make it executable using `chmod +x mixup_pcap.sh`, and then run it using `./mixup_pcap.sh`.
4. Analyze the mixed-up pcap file: You can open the generated mixed-up pcap file (`mixed_sessions.pcap`) in Wireshark or use Tshark to analyze it further.

Note: Make sure you have Tshark installed on your system to execute the above steps.

To mix up sessions in a `pcap` file using Tshark or Wireshark, you can use the following steps:

1. Rename the original pcap file to something else (optional): This step is not necessary but can help keep track of the original pcap file. You can use the following command to rename the file:

   ```shell
   mv original.pcap original_original.pcap
   ```
2. Extract individual sessions from the original `pcap` file using Tshark: Use Tshark to extract individual sessions from the original `pcap` file into separate pcap files, like this:

   ```shell
   tshark -r original_original.pcap -Y "tcp.stream == X" -w session_X.pcap
   ```

   Replace `X` with the desired session number. Repeat this command for each session you want to extract, incrementing `X` accordingly.
3. Mix up the extracted `pcap` files: Use a bash script to randomly concatenate the extracted pcap files into a new mixed-up pcap file. Here is an example script (`mixup_pcap.sh`) that uses the `shuf` command to shuffle the filenames randomly and then appends them to a new file:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   output_pcap="mixed_sessions.pcap"
   session_files=(session_*.pcap)

   # Randomly shuffle the session files
   shuffled_files=($(shuf -e "${session_files[@]}"))

   # Concatenate the shuffled pcap files into a new mixed-up pcap file
   for file in "${shuffled_files[@]}"; do
       cat "$file" >> "$output_pcap"
   done

   echo "Mixed-up pcap file created: $output_pcap"
   ```

   Save the above script to `mixup_pcap.sh`, make it executable using `chmod +x mixup_pcap.sh`, and then run it using `./mixup_pcap.sh`.
4. Analyze the mixed-up pcap file: You can open the generated mixed-up pcap file (`mixed_sessions.pcap`) in Wireshark or use Tshark to analyze it further.

Note: Make sure you have Tshark installed on your system to execute the above steps.

Comment: didn't know pcap files could just be concatenated! And: Does shuffling the files make any sense? pcap entries contain timestamps. What is it that you actually want to have in the resulting pcap file? lines that are out-of-order according to their timestamps?

Comment: Could you add a link to the original script? It might help to understand the context.